# Glitch on Windows Forms when Data Binding on a property called Property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I was experimenting with Data Binding in Windows Forms and found a glitch that I can't explain. I post the question here in hopes that someone in the community can come up with an answer that makes sense.

I tried to come up with a clever way of binding read-only values that depend on operations on other values, and update it automatically when the dependent values change.

I created a form with 3 textboxes, where I want the sum of the first 2 to appear in the 3rd textbox.

The following code should work, but doesn't, at least not properly:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int m_valueA;
    private int m_valueB;

    public int ValueA
    {
        get { return m_valueA; }
        set { m_valueA = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ValueA"); }
    }

    public int ValueB
    {
        get { return m_valueB; }
        set { m_valueB = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ValueB"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class DynamicBindingProperty<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Func<T> m_function;
    private HashSet<string> m_properties;

    public DynamicBindingProperty(Func<T> function, INotifyPropertyChanged container, IEnumerable<string> properties)
    {
        m_function = function;
        m_properties = new HashSet<string>(properties);
        container.PropertyChanged += DynamicBindingProperty_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public T Property { get { return m_function(); } }

    void DynamicBindingProperty_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_properties.Contains(e.PropertyName)) return;
        if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeDataBinding();
    }

    private void InitializeDataBinding()
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        DynamicBindingProperty<int> tmp = new DynamicBindingProperty<int>(() => model.ValueA + model.ValueB, model, new[] {"ValueA", "ValueB"});

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", model, "ValueA");
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", model, "ValueB");
        textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", tmp, "Property");

        tmp.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

After experimenting for a while, I tried renaming DynamicBindingProperty<T>.Property to something else (e.g. DynamicProperty), and **everything worked as expected!**. Now, I was expecting something to break by renaming Model.ValueA to Property, but it didn't, and still worked flawlessly.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some debugging and it looks like a bug (or requirement "the property must not be named Property" I am not aware of). If you replace

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property"));
```

with

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
```

it still does not work - `null` or an empty string means any property may have changed. This indicates that problem is not in the handling of the change notification but that the binding has not been correctly established.

If you add a second property `Property2` to `DynamicBindingProperty<T>` that does the same as `Property` and bind it to a fourth text box, then *both* text boxes will get update correctly  if you perform a change notification with an empty string, `null` or `"Property2"`. If you perform the change notification with `"Property"` *both* text boxes will *not* get update correctly. This indicates that the binding to `Property` is not completely broken and also that the change notification is somewhat broken.

Sadly I was unable to pin down the exact location where things go wrong, but if you invest enough time stepping through optimized framework source code you can probably figure it out. The earliest difference between the case with property name `Property` and the case with property name `Property2` I could identify when processing a change notification was in `OnValueChanged()` in the internal class `System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor`. In one case the base implementation gets called while it gets skipped in the other case - at least if the debugger didn't trick me, but this is hard to tell in optimized code.